# Why I encounter a NULL terminating character at start of a string when I go backwards through it?

Tags: c, string, pointers, dereference, decrement

I found the following piece of code embedded in a C++ project. The code goes backwards through a C-style string. When I saw this I thought this should result in undefined behaviour. But it seems to work perfectly:

```
const char * hello = "Hello World.";
const char * helloPointPos = strchr(hello, '.');
for (const char * curchar = helloPointPos; *curchar; curchar--) {
  printf("%s", curchar);
}
```

What I was wondering about is the part with `*curchar; curchar--`. This assumes that the string begins with a \0. Is this a legal assumption? Does this piece of code result in undefined behaviour? If not, why not?

I would appreciate if you could put some light on this. BTW platform is Windows and Compiler is VC++ 2010.

**EDIT :** Thank you all for your participation. Both answers are very good and helped me. But since I can only accept one answer I will go for paxdiablo's answer since it has more detail. Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's very much not a requirement that the character before a string be `\0`, so that code does not have defined behaviour.

In fact, it's *doubly* undefined since you're not permitted to derefernce a pointer that's not within the array or one byte beyond the end. Since this is dereferencing one byte *before* the array, it's invalid in that sense as well.

It *may* work in some situations<sup>(a)</sup> but it's by no means good code.

In any case, the printing of the string rather than the character is going to give you strange results:

```
.d.ld.rld.orld.World. World.
```

and so on.

A better reverse iterator would be something like:

```
char *curchar = &(hello[strlen (hello)]);  // one byte beyond
while (curchar-- != hello)                 // check if reached start, post-decr
    putchar (*curchar);                    // just the character, thanks.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> In fact, it's often one of the most annoying things about undefined behaviour is that it sometimes *does* work, lulling you into a false sense of security.

I've often thought that all coders should have electrical wires hooked up to their most private parts so that undefined behaviour could deliver a short sharp shock - I suspect there would be a lot less undefined behaviour (or far fewer developers) after a while :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's certainly not defined behavior, but in this case it isn't surprising that it works.

`const char * hello = "Hello World.";` puts the string `Hello World.` in a section with all other string literals. So very likely, there's a string literal before it, and it ends with `\0`, so there's `\0`' before `Hello World.`, and the code works.

Obviously you can't rely on it - you're string might be the first in the section, or some non-string constant may be in there. Also, if the string is allocated any other way, chances to get `\0` before it are lower.

Comment: You can see an example of a situation where that loop condition will fail in the next piece of code:
 char * a = "BYE";
 char * c = "HELLO";
 *(a+3) = 'L'; 
 printf(">%d\t%d\n", *(--c),'\0');

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo, modifying `*(a+3)` is, in this case, undefined behavior in itself (`"BYE"` is a constant). Anyway, I never said it's guaranteed to have `\0` before a constant string.